# Why is MKMapView delegate method not being called?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm very new to iphone development and I'm trying to annotate a map. I've been able to get 3 location points on a map with hardcoded coordinates and now I'm trying to customize the pins. I know to do that you need to implement the:`-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {` delegate method.

For some reason I've been unable to even get it called. Here is what I have in the controller header:

```
#import "ArtPiece.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    MKMapView *mapView;
    NSMutableArray *mapAnnotations;
    float results_lat[3];
    float results_long[3];
    NSMutableArray *results_title;
    NSMutableArray *Arts;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mapAnnotations;

@end
```

And here is what I have in the controller implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    results_long[0] = -122.477989;
    results_lat[0] = 37.810000;
    results_long[1] = -122.480000;
    results_lat[1] = 37.820000;
    results_long[2] = -122.4850000;
    results_lat[2] = 37.830000;

    self.mapAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    Arts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    for(int x = 0; x<3; x++)
    {
        // creates an ArtPiece object and sets its lat and long
        ArtPiece *a = [[ArtPiece alloc] init];
        a.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:results_long[x]];
        a.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:results_lat[x]];
        a.title = @"please show up";
        // add objects to annotation array
        [self.mapAnnotations insertObject:a atIndex:x];
        [a release];

    }
    // center screen on cali area
    [self gotoLocation];
    for(int x = 0; x<3; x++)
    {
        [mapView addAnnotations:mapAnnotations];
    }
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    NSLog(@"This is not printing to to console...");
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple; 
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    } 
    else {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

And here is the ArtPiece class implementation:

```
   #import "TestViewController.h"
    #import "ArtPiece.h"
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

    @implementation ArtPiece

    @synthesize title, artist, series, description, latitude, longitude;

    - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = [self.latitude doubleValue];
        theCoordinate.longitude = [self.longitude doubleValue];
        return theCoordinate;
    }



    @end
```

It's probably something simple. Is there something wrong with my method declaration? Did I declare the delegate wrong? I can't figure it out, again, I'm very new to this objective c/delegate stuff. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addAnnotations` method expects an NSArray of objects that conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

You are adding objects of type `ArtPiece` which don't seem to implement MKAnnotation which has a `coordinate` property (not `latitude` and `longitude` properties).

Update your `ArtPiece` class to conform to `MKAnnotation` (or use the pre-defined `MKPointAnnotation` class).  But updating your custom class is a better fix.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback! I edited my question to include the ArtPiece class. I think it has the coordinate protocol which is being set by the latitude and longitude data members. And I think it must be conforming to the MKAnnotation protocol because my map does display the default red pins. But maybe I'm mistaken? Does looking at the ArtPiece class give you any other ideas or confirm your first answer?

Comment: Ok, if you do see at least red pins then ArtPiece must be ok.  Then it must be something simple like: in Interface Builder, did you connect the map view's delegate to the TestViewController's File Owner?

Comment: If the delegate connection is ok in IB, then post the ArtPiece.h file.

Comment: You're good! That's exactly what the problem was, I forgot to make that connection. Thanks again for the quick and helpful feedback!